# nothing paints on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, crash, jframe

I am having some trouble with my code which is written in java. The first time after I start eclipse it launches and runs perfectly, but if I try to run it again - without making any changes - the only thing I see is an empty JFrame. Why might this happen? I have gotten quite a bit of files so to launch them all up here would be a lot to look through. Maybe you've tried something like this before? Where the program can launch sometimes? If not tell me so I can add the code.

I know that all of my classes are called since I have printed them all in my search to get the game to work.

The entire code worked until I started to put most of it in different objects in order to make it easier to look through.

```
package Pacman;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Frame extends JFrame{
public static int Width, Height;
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Width = console.nextInt();
    Height = console.nextInt();
    new Frame();
}

public Frame(){
    new JFrame();

    this.setTitle("PacMan");
    this.setLocation(400,300);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setVisible(true);

    Screen screen = new Screen(this, Width, Height);
    this.add(screen);

}

}
```

This is the JFrame, but I am pretty sure the problem isn't here.

If you want to see the entire codesystem it's at github: https://github.com/Lampeskaerm/SoftTek_Projekt.git

I hope you can help me
Anne-Katrine

Comment: you will have to show us some code... Atleast the part where you are actually using the JFrame...

Comment: show how you construct your main `JFrame` seems problem in that.

Comment: You are right in guessing we don't want to see all the hundreds of lines of your code. Begin by backing up your current work, then removing everything from it which you don't find essential to reproducing the problem. As you progress, you'll probably find the exact spot which causse the problem.

Comment: The problem is Marko that the code worked when it was more or less all in the same java file - now I have split it up and somewhere there is a mistake which I have spent 2 days to find... I am running out of time :/ And I have already done what you suggested...

Comment: there is a mistake - your mistake is already answered and correctly

Comment: I figured it out... My view object was called too late so it messed up my code :) Thanks for the feedback on this weird question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After adding the component you should use this.setVisible(true) in the last.

Comment: It didn't change anything :/

Comment: It didn't change anything - most important things because you added something to the already visible JFrame, rest is elsewhere